# How can i transfer the results from one variable to a column in excel?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add the values inside `duplicates` to column `Name` so that `print(data["Name"])` can return all the values contained by the `duplicates`. How can I achieve this?

Quick story: I'm importing a csv file and I need to split the column `Name` to get rid of meaningless information and then I'm using list comprehension to find the duplicates.

```
data = pd.read_csv(next(iglob('*.csv')))
data["Name"]= data["Name"].str.split("(", n = 1, expand = True) 
duplicates = [x for x in data["Name"]  if x in data["Name"] 
[data["Name"].duplicated()].values]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
df['dupicates'] = df['Name'].where(df['Name'].duplicated(keep=False), '')

    Name duplicates
0  NameC           
1  NameA      NameA
2  NameB      NameB
3  NameA      NameA
4  NameA      NameA
5  NameB      NameB
```

Or if you only want to label those duplicate values...(remove `keep=False`)

```
df['duplicates'] = df['Name'].where(df['Name'].duplicated(), '')

    Name duplicates
0  NameC           
1  NameA           
2  NameB           
3  NameA      NameA
4  NameA      NameA
5  NameB      NameB
```

---

IIUC, you can try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['NameC', 'NameA', 'NameB', 'NameA', 'NameA', 'NameB']})
duplicates = df.loc[df['Name'].duplicated(), 'Name'].unique().tolist()
duplicates
```

Output:

```
['NameA', 'NameB']
```

Explanation: Use `duplicates` to create a boolean series, then filter the dataframe by the boolean series and column 'Name' then use unique to get the unique values of all the duplicates.

Comment: maybe you think `keep=False` ?

Comment: But `unique` will get a single value suppose I had NameC in the frame once. Right?  I don't want NameC.

Comment: In Scott example, my code will return NameA, NameA, NameA - this is exactly why i used list comprehension, otherwise NameA will be seen for just two times. Now, i want the results found in "duplicates" to be written back to the initial column they came from (from column Name in the csv file). I've tried data["Name"] = duplicates but it's stupid and it doesn't work.

Comment: @bogdann I am sorry. I don't follow.  Can you add some sample data and expected output to your question. Maybe jezrael understands better.

Comment: So, in the .csv file, the column named Name contains a bunch of names: NameA, NameB, NameA etc. The variable "duplicates" find the duplicates in that column. Now, the only thing i don't know is how to populate the excel file with the findings. At the end i'm using to_excel() to create a new excel that will contain the script results...